# How do I build only one class of Espresso Instrument APK file?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, automated-tests, android-espresso

I had read these [documents from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/mobile/getting-started-with-android-testing-on-aws-device-farm-using-espresso-part-3-uploading-your-android-application-to-aws-device-farm/), learning how to use Espresso testing on AWS.

Then, I made 3 different classes for different tests.

In this step, I selected only one ‘class’ in the Configuration setting,
and run it by right click, only this LaunchActivityTest class runs on my device.

[image]
[image]

But while I upload the *app-alpha-debug-androidTest.apk* to AWS Device Farm,
I found that all of my 3 testing class are build in this APK.

How do I build only one class of Espresso Instrument APK file?